# Why did/do they torture people to get fake "confessions"?

Tags: law, 17th-century, crime, 16th-century, torture

I've always wondered about why they would torture somebody to get a fake "confession", just so they can then execute the same person.

Why not just execute them from the beginning? Why go through the ridiculous charade if you aren't going to perform the investigation for real anyway?

It goes without saying that any confession to a crime while being tortured is worthless. Yet I've read so many Wikipedia pages about historical figures who were treated exactly like this, and then killed for the crime which they (maybe) only admitted to because they wanted the torture to stop.

I know I couldn't bare the mildest form of torture without immediately admitting to every crime ever, just so that the pain would stop.

Comment: The scientific analysis that torture isn't a worthwhile form of interrogation is fairly recent. Can you be sure that back in the 16th-17th centuries they actually knew it was a "ridiculous charade"?

Comment: You may want to specify the exact era and nation you're asking about -- standards and procedures varied a *lot*. E.g., the Spanish vs Italian Inquisitions.)

Comment: It's also wise to avoid questions which boil down to "How could they have been so stupid back then?" They were not stupid -- though they were often ignorant -- and what they did usually made sense in context.

Comment: Um... I can't tell if you two are being serious or not. Are you suggesting that people a few hundred years ago were so dumb that they "didn't realize" that torturing somebody obviously doesn't produce the truth, but only what they want to hear?

Comment: In justice systems of the past, it was not always seen as desirable that the guilty were punished, so much as that the sovereign was seen to hand out punishment to *someone.* This is no different from (for example) lengthy pre-trial detention coercing suspects to falsely plead guilty today.

Comment: Of the men executed on trumped-up charges of adultery with Anne Boleyn, only the musician Mark Smeaton was allegedly tortured because he was of humble birth and the others were 'gentlemen'.

Comment: "On Crimes and Punishments" (1764) by Cesare Beccaria might be an interesting reading, because it was a fundamental text on criminal law. It condemned very heavily torture for confessions as being cruel, because a person was being punished before knowing if they were guilty or not; *and* ineffective, because strong guilty people could stand it while weak innocent people succumbed to it.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786). Is there a reason to believe that historical sources and methods will help to answer this question.  Please read [help]

Comment: Boring non answer - a crime has been done. There is social pressure to find the culprit and make them pay. You can A spend a lot of time and effort before the current era of forensics trying to find the actual culprit who may turn out to be untouchable due rank or distance (or just unknown). Or B you can find someone unpopular, get a confession and be in the pub for lunch.

Comment: @Kayode "people a few hundred years ago were so dumb" no need to look into history. The self proclaimed leader of the free world has been officially doing it just a few years ago. Still doing it if you believe the UN.

Comment: Another text about the reprehensibility of torture is [Cautio Criminalis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cautio_Criminalis), written 1631 by Jesuit [Friedrich Spee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Spee) in refutation of the 1486 [Hammer of Witches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleus_Maleficarum). The German witch hunt craze or the 16th/17th century is a good example of how the practice of torture just feeds itself: once you have started, you must go on or accept that you are the true criminal yourself.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest (but rather depressing) answer is that there's no enlightened logic to it at all. Its just that people under the right circumstances can do evil things to other people. We humans are creatures that are capable of logic, yes, but we're still humans.

Let's talk about one fairly well-documented case of it being used: The Bush Era "War on Terror", and its so-called [Enhanced Interrogation Techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_interrogation_techniques).

Its fairly accepted academically that torture is a [bit better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torture#Confession) for getting the victim to say what (they think) you want than for getting the *truth* out of someone. However, one thing I got from reading [Jane Mayer's *The Dark Side*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Side_(book)) was that all indications were that both the Bush Administration people pushing for it and the people carrying it out largely honestly (but incorrectly) believed they were getting lots of good useful info out of it. Evidence to the contrary was not wanting, and in fact there are multiple cases where a false information caused real harm. However, it just seems like they didn't *want* to believe otherwise.

> Complicating Goldsmith's efforts to push the Bush Administration's secret programs back inside the law was their reputed success. On the other side of the globe, in an undisclosed location, the CIA's clandestine efforts were more than justifying themselves in the eyes of the administration's top officials.

[CIA Director Tenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Tenet) for example repeatedly told officials that Kahlid Sheik Mohammed ("KSM") was providing a "gold mine" of information under torture. According to Mayer, a top CIA official asked for some of that info to share with "an allied foreign intelligence agency", and was told there actually wasn't *anything* solid enough to give, even in confidence. KSM later recanted a great deal of what he "confessed" under torture. As of today he is still in US custody and has still not stood trial for anything.

There was also the case of [Khaled el-Masri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khalid_El-Masri), a car salesman from Germany, who got picked up largely due to having a fresh passport and an Arabic name, and was turned over to the US and tortured for more than a year. Internal memos show that the agents taking him in were quite certain they had an innocent man even *before his plane touched down*, but the higher-ups didn't want to hear it.

> Almost from the start, the rendition team has a strange feeling about Masri. He wasn't acting like a terrorist. By the time their flight reached Afghanistan, the head of the rendition team sent word to the CIA station chief in Kabul that he thought something wasn't right. The Kabul station chief was incensed and sent a cable to the CTC accusing Langley of having sent him an innocent person. But the CTC officials sent back word that the head of the Al Qaeda Unit wanted Masri held and interrogated. She thought he seemed suspicious.

I have another book [Becoming Evil](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195148681) that delves a bit more into the psychology of people who participate in genocide. That's of course different than torture, but aside from both being evil, one has to suspect the psychology involved in getting people to perpetrate them are similar. A lot of the typical elements are similar.

- A belief that you are actually the one under attack
- A culture of cruelty.
- A dehumanization of the victims.
- Blaming the victims for their own victimization ("must have done something to deserve it")
- Professional self-interest in the evil activity

I've included a couple of charts from the book below. My apologies for them being grainy photos of crude charts, but I didn't want to hide their authorship in any way.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**"Justice must be done, and it must be seen to be done."**

One could argue that for the functioning of a society, the second part is more important than the first. It won't be a *nice* society if it regularly tortures and punishes innocent people, but it might be a *workable* society -- more so than any society without visible justice.

- A **confession** may be seen as necessary for the **salvation** of the **sinner**. That sentence brings the Inquisition to mind (Spanish or otherwise), but the boundary between secular law and religion used to be weaker than it is today. There are many legal systems where a convict who proclaims innocence will have a harder time getting parole than a convict who "comes to terms" with the crime and "repents/reforms."
  So what to do when a confession isn't happening voluntarily?
- Forensic evidence is rather new. Practical [fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint#20th_century) is a bit over a century old, practical DNA analysis goes back just a few decades. So **without eyewitness accounts**, getting a confession was seen as better than just [circumstantial evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstantial_evidence).
- There were many cases/times where law enforcement would "zero in" on the suspect based on things that were **not admissible in court** (professional experience/instincts, or bias and prejudice). They would then have to "supply" the evidence to make their feeling stick, and a [forcibly extracted confession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_confession) solves their problem.

Answer (score 0):

On occasion: so the state may confiscate the property of the accused and disinherit his dependents.

This was the case when in 1692 [Giles Corey](https://historyofmassachusetts.org/the-curse-of-giles-corey/) was [accused of witchcraft](https://blogs.loc.gov/law/2020/10/the-crushing-death-of-giles-corey-of-salem-1692/) and refused in open court to accept a trial by his peers, instead *standing mute*. As the story goes Corey was then **pressed** in attempts to coerce an acceptance, by successively piling greater and greater weights on his chest. It's claimed that as each rock was placed on his chest, Corey kept repeating only "More weight." After a few days of this Corey succumbed; but as his estate could only be confiscated **following** a guilty verdict, and customs of the time only allowed a trial following a plea, his property passed to his dependents instead of the State of Massachusetts.